# C++ intrusive_ptr issue

Tags: c++, boost, namespaces, smart-pointers, forward-declaration

I want to use `boost::intrusive_ptr` for refcounting my class `x::Y`, so I add a `references` field and friend declarations for the `release` and `add_ref` functions, which should be defined in namespace `boost`. Then, I write those functions. Like this:

```
namespace x{


    class Y{
        long    references;
        friend void boost::intrusive_ptr_add_ref(x::Y * p);
        friend void boost::intrusive_ptr_release(x::Y * p);
    };
}

namespace boost
{
    void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(x::Y * p)
    {
        ++(p->references);
    }

    void intrusive_ptr_release(x::Y * p)
    {
        if (--(p->references) == 0)
            delete p;
    }
}
```

The code does not compile, I receive the following errors:

```
test/test6.cpp:8:18: error: ‘boost’ has not been declared
test/test6.cpp:9:18: error: ‘boost’ has not been declared
test/test6.cpp: In function ‘void boost::intrusive_ptr_add_ref(x::Y*)’:
test/test6.cpp:7:11: error: ‘long int x::Y::references’ is private
test/test6.cpp:17:9: error: within this context
test/test6.cpp: In function ‘void boost::intrusive_ptr_release(x::Y*)’:
test/test6.cpp:7:11: error: ‘long int x::Y::references’ is private
test/test6.cpp:22:13: error: within this context
```

I thought I did everthing like explained by the boost documentation, but it seems that I did something wrong. Where is the problem?

Comment: Why do you want intrusive ref count? What's wrong with `shared_ptr` here, since your class is orignally not ref counted.

Comment: please stick to the issue. This is only a minimal example for explaining my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors are because you are referring to the `boost` namespace in your class definition, before any declaration of that namespace. You can fix it by declaring `namespace boost` before your class definition; you'll also need to declare the functions, and to do that you'll also need to declare the class and namespace:

```
namespace x {class Y;}
namespace boost
{
    void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(x::Y * p);
    void intrusive_ptr_release(x::Y * p);
}
```

However, if might be better to put the functions not in the `boost` namespace, but in the namespace containing your class (i.e. in `namespace x`). Then `intrusive_ptr` will find the correct version by argument-dependent name lookup. This doesn't require any declarations before the class.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular minimal code, you seem to be missing something to the effect of

```
namespace x { class Y; }
namespace boost {
        void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(x::Y * p);
        void intrusive_ptr_release(x::Y * p);
}
```

in the beginning. That is, forward-declare Y and declare your functions. Though why would you want to go through this pain just to put your functions into the namespace where they do not belong is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward declare them.

If your compiler supports Argument Dependent Lookup, you should put the functions `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` and `intrusive_ptr_release` into your own namespace, and forward declare them there as well.

```
namespace x{
    void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(x::Y * p);

    void intrusive_ptr_release(x::Y * p);

    class Y{
        long    references;
        friend void boost::intrusive_ptr_add_ref(x::Y * p);
        friend void boost::intrusive_ptr_release(x::Y * p);
    };

    void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(x::Y * p)
    {
        ++(p->references);
    }

    void intrusive_ptr_release(x::Y * p)
    {
        if (--(p->references) == 0)
            delete p;
    }
}
```

Edit: If you would prefer to put them in the boost namespace, you can do that instead, by forward declaring the boost namespace with those two function declarations in it prior to your class.

Answer (score 1):

You can define these functions in `namespace x`. But if you want to declare functions in `namespace boost`, use something like this

```
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>

namespace x
{
   class Y;
}

namespace boost
{
    void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(x::Y * p);
    /*{
        ++(p->references);
    }*/

    void intrusive_ptr_release(x::Y * p);
    /*{
        if (--(p->references) == 0)
            delete p;
    }*/
}

namespace x{

    class Y{
        long    references;
        friend void boost::intrusive_ptr_add_ref(x::Y * p);
        friend void boost::intrusive_ptr_release(x::Y * p);
    };
}

namespace boost
{
    void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(x::Y * p)
    {
        ++(p->references);
    }

    void intrusive_ptr_release(x::Y * p)
    {
        if (--(p->references) == 0)
            delete p;
    }
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/99cb62380019ccb39993f0a9e656eff2

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you define [`intrusive_ptr_add_ref`](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html#Introduction) and [`intrusive_ptr_release`](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html#Introduction) in the same namespace as the class `::x::Y`, namely in `::x`.

Answer (score 0):

The first errro suggests that you didn't include any boost headers. The remainder is because that first error causes parse failures on the `friend` declarations.